# Equality of fuzzy sets

Tags: terminology, definition, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

**Is there a definition for "equality of fuzzy sets" ?**

My current thinking :

Say we have two fuzzy sets $A = \{(x,\mu_{A}(x)):x \in X\}$ and $B = \{(y,\mu_{B}(y)):y \in Y\}$

When we consider equality of fuzzy sets , then for making $A = B$ , we might want :

- (I) $X = Y$
- (II) $\mu_{A}(x) = \mu_{B}(x)$

Are these 2 conditions (I) & (II) necessary ?

Alternately , we can consider like this :

- (III) $support(A) = support(B)$
- (IV) $x \in support(A) \Rightarrow \mu_{A}(x) = \mu_{B}(x)$

Are these 2 conditions (III) & (IV) sufficient ?

A simple example for clarifying my question:

Are two fuzzy sets $A$ and $B$ with the following definitions equal?

$$ A = 0.1/0 $$
$$ B = 0.1/0 + 0/1 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **Jon Y. Kim** , ["Introduction to Fuzzy Set Theory"](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/336_20/papers19/Jon.pdf) ,  Equality of Fuzzy Sets can be achieved easily , though the Initial Definition of Fuzzy Set itself requires a little tweaking like this :

Whereas OP has used Collection $X$ in Fuzzy Set $A$ & Collection $Y$ in Fuzzy Set $B$ , it seems to be more standard to have Single Universal Collection , for which I will use $U$ here , to avoid confusion with the other existing letters.
Each Fuzzy Set then uses Collection $U$ and will have the membership function $\mu$.

**Definition** (Fuzzy Set) If $U$ is a collection of objects denoted generically by $u$, then a fuzzy set $A$ in $X$ is a set of ordered pairs :
$A = \{(u, \mu_A(u)) : u \in U\}$
where $\mu_A(u)$ is the membership function which maps $u$ to a real number in the interval $[0, 1]$

Then $A=\{(u,\mu_A(u)):u \in U\}$ and $B=\{(u,\mu_B(u)):u \in U\}$
We no longer require OP Condition (I) , which is automatically true.
[[ When OP had $X$ & $Y$ not equal , in general , then $U$ will contain at least $X \cup Y$ , with suitable $\mu=0$ to exclude the unwanted elements are inserted between $X,Y,U$ ]]

Now , **Kim Jon** makes the Equality Definition like this :

**Definition** (Empty Fuzzy Set) A fuzzy set $A$ is empty if and only if its membership function is identically zero on $X$, $\mu_A \equiv 0$

**Definition** (Fuzzy Set Equality) Two fuzzy sets $A$ and $B$ are equal if and only if $\mu_A(x) = \mu_B(x)$ for all $x ∈ X$. We will denote equality as $A = B$

This matches OP Condition (II) , which is necessary & sufficient here.

Moving to OP Condition (III) , we see that it is necessary , but not sufficient. When Supports are Equal , we can not say Fuzzy Sets are Equal , because the membership functions might not match.
We then include OP Condition (IV) , which says that membership functions are equal within the Common Support.
Now , Fuzzy Set Equality is achieved , but (III) is redundant.
We know that elements outside the Support have $\mu_A(u)=0=\mu_B(u)$ , thus , it is Equal within & outside the Support , throughout Common Universal Set $U$ !
Thus (IV) is enough , provided we use the Fuzzy Set Definition with Common Universal Set $U$.
When we do not use Common Universal Set $U$ , then (III) + (IV) are sufficient too.

**Kim Jon** uses Concepts from **Zadeh** & **Zimmerman** , hence it is somewhat standardized.

EXAMPLE :

$A = 0.1/0$
$B = 0.1/0 + 0/1$

We have to write it out with Common Universal Collection $U$ , which should contain at least the Union of the 2 Supports.
Let $U=\{0,1,2,3\}$
$A = 0.1/0 + 0.0/1 + 0.0/2 + 0.0/3$
$B = 0.1/0 + 0.0/1 + 0.0/2 + 0.0/3$
$C = 0.1/0 + 0.0/1 + 0.0/2 + 1.0/3$
$D = 0.0/0 + 0.0/1 + 0.0/2 + 0.0/3$
Now (I) is automatically true.
More-over (II) is also true.
Hence we have $A=B$ here.
It is not true that $A=C$ & $B=C$ , because membership function will not match for at least 1 element.
Like-wise , $A=D$ & $B=D$ & $C=D$ can not be true.

Lastly "D = Empty Fuzzy Set" is true.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I edited my question and appended a simple question to it. Can you add a clear answer to it?

Comment: Where did you use the definition of `Empty Fuzzy Set`?

Comment: I did not use Empty Fuzzy Set , I gave that Definition , to use when we want to make such equality like "A = Empty Fuzzy Set" , while in all other Cases , we have to use the Equality Definition.

Comment: I have updated with the Example , @hasanghaforian , you can check it now. Let me know whether something is not clear !

Comment: Why we can assume that after extending the universe of $A$ from $\{0\}$ to $\{0,1,2,3\}$ its membership for all new elements is $0$? Where documents assert this? It is like when you want to expand the domain of a function and you can map any new element in to any element in range of function. Even the range of function may vary, although for memberships it will remain again $[0,1]$.

Comment: (( 1 )) When we say that $3$ is not a member , it is same as saying membership is not Positive , which is same as saying membership is $0$ (( 2 )) To avoid issues like you mention , that is why Jon / Zimmerman / Zadeh insist that Universal Set $U$ must be Common & non-members must have membership value $0$ (( 3 )) With your way , what will be the value for $\mu(c)$ when $c$ is not a member ? (( 4 )) Common Sense thinking will assert that the value is $0$ , otherwise non-member will suddenly become member !! (( 5 )) What other value can you justify here ?

Comment: Recently I asked another question in about Fuzzy logic. Can you say your opinion about that, there? math.stackexchange.com/q/4859985/21779